# unable to read a url from a app deployed on wls

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

My application is deployed on `Weblogic` server and the following code

```
    private boolean validateParse() {
    URLConnection yc = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Processing source:" + source);
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            boolean aFlag = false;
            boolean tFlag = false;
            boolean lFlag = false;
            boolean pFlag = false;
            Map<String, String> rec = null;
            List<Map<String, String>> dataSet =
                new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                                     String qName,
                                     Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("author"))
                    aFlag = true;
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                    tFlag = true;
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                    lFlag = true;
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
                    pFlag = true;
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                                   String qName) throws SAXException {
                if (rec.containsKey("pubDate") &&
                    rec.containsKey("author") &&
                    rec.containsKey("title") && rec.containsKey("link")) {
                    rec.clear();
                }
            }

            public void characters(char[] ch, int start,
                                   int length) throws SAXException {

                if (tFlag) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    rec = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    rec.put("title", new String(ch, start, length));
                    tFlag = false;
                }

                if (lFlag) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    rec.put("link", new String(ch, start, length));
                    lFlag = false;
                }

                if (aFlag) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    rec.put("author", new String(ch, start, length));
                    aFlag = false;
                }

                if (pFlag) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
                    rec.put("pubDate", new String(ch, start, length));
                    dataSet.add(rec);
                    pFlag = false;
                }
            }

            public void endDocument() {
            }
        };

        URL google = new URL(source);
        yc = google.openConnection();
        saxParser.parse(yc.getInputStream(), handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            yc.getInputStream().close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
} //end startParsing
```

which gives exception as:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unsupported protocol: https'
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:384)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:252)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:189)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:661)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:440)
at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37)
at vik.tools.changeNotifier.ui.bean.AdminBean.validateParse(AdminBean.java:125)
at vik.tools.changeNotifier.ui.bean.AdminBean.addSource(AdminBean.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:53)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding(UIXComponentBase.java:1256)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:183)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:92)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:361)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:96)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:102)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:92)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:361)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:96)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:96)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:788)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:306)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:186)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:175)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

any idea how can i resolve it?

Comment: Not without the full stack and the value of the 'source' variable...  Also, which line in your snippet causes the exception?

Comment: saxParser.parse(yc.getInputStream(), handler); is the line getting the exception.  I modified my post to add rest of the stack trace

Comment: You're really not providing much to work with.  What is 'handler'?  Please edit your post to provide the full stack trace and error message starting from the first line.

Comment: Sorry about it. I updated the post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL is using HTTPS and the problem could be that https is not supported for the host+URI you are using.  Try using HTTP instead.

Comment: it is http only. i admit the url is secure on intranet. but i m reading it on a computer running on intranet only.

Comment: The exception states: "Unsupported protocol: https'".  Perhaps there is a typo in your URL.  Is the ' character in your URL string?

Answer (score 0):

Configure in `setDomainENV.cmd` which is under the`WL_home/user_projects/domain/bin/`
in this file place the following the command at the end of the file

> > set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %JAVA_PROPERTIES% -Dwlw.iterativeDev=%iterativeDevFlag% -Dwlw.testConsole=%testConsoleFlag% -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=%logErrorsToConsoleFlag% -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true  -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dhttps.proxySet=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=YOU ARE USING IP ADDRESS -Dhttps.proxyPort=YOU ARE USING PORT

Then restart the server then it will work

But it is bad practices in production.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  The code runs fine from my IDE but not when deployed to WebLogic.

In my case the issue was that the end server redirects to an "https" url.  Java URLConnection follows the redirect silently.  To fix the issue I just set redirect to false and do the url follow manually

```
    HttpURLConnection con = getUrlConnection(urlStr);
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

The thread below really helps.

[Is it possible for a site having URL starting with "http://" using HTTPS protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161386/is-it-possible-for-a-site-having-url-starting-with-http-using-https-protoco)